How to simulate a drone with moveit2 and a floating joint?
I am trying to simulate a "drone" and use moveit for the motion planning aspect of thing.
In my minimal example I want to launch moveit with a simple cude link that will act as the drone with a floating joint bellow it that will give me the desired 6 DOFs.
<robot name="floating_drone">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="floating_1" type="floating">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="Drone1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.0"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <!-- <limit effort="10" lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" velocity="1.0"/> -->
  </joint>

  <link name="Drone1">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0001666666666666667" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001666666666666667" iyz="0" izz="0.0001666666666666667"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot> 

I used the setup assistant to create the package but i get the following errors when I run the demo.launch.py.

[robot_state_publisher-1] [WARN] [1725535652.268564490] [kdl_parser]: Converting unknown joint type of joint 'floating_1' into a fixed joint


[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725535652.268649451] [robot_state_publisher]: Floating joint. Not adding segment from base_link to Drone1.


[move_group-2] [WARN] [1725535652.301535730] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Unable to update multi-DOF joint 'floating_1':Failure to lookup transform between 'base_link'and 'Drone1' with TF exception: "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.


[rviz2-3] [ERROR] [1725535655.995792239] [moveit_robot_state.robot_state]: Unknown type of joint in Jacobian computation


[rviz2-3] [WARN] [1725535655.995957038] [kdl_parser]: Converting unknown joint type of joint 'floating_1' into a fixed joint

Does that mean that Moviet2 doesn't support floating joints? I tried also using 3 revolute joints and one prismatic to make a pseudo floating but that doesn't produce the desired outcome.
Any recomendations?
